# Android - Google OAuth 2 - twice response with different verifier code

Tags: android, google-oauth, nativescript

I have an issue with Oauth Google on Android 9 and lower.

**Settings :**

I develop an application with :

- Nativescript 7
- Angular 11
- nativescript-oauth2:3.0.3 plugin

**The problem :**

I am not sure the problem is from the nativescript-oauth2 plugin, perhaps my android application configuration or Google Frame.

I develop an OAuth login with Facebook and Google provider.
For Facebook, no problem.

Facebook use a web view browser, and Google use a native view browser.

For Google, see bellow :

- on emulator with android 10 : all work fine
- on emulator with android 8 or 9 :

  - it open the browser to login with Google => I choose my account => redirect to a Google Page with Waiting message => it never redirect to my app, and after a moment, it redirect to `www.google.com`
- on real device (android 9) with multiple Google account, I have 2 behaviors :

  - First : it open the browser to login with Google => I choose my account => redirect to a Google Page with "Waiting" message => redirect to my App with `The login operation was canceled` error message
  - Second : it open the browser to login with Google => **I wait a moment (per example 1 minute)** => I choose my account => redirect to a Google Page with `Waiting message` => redirect to my App => it work fine
- on other real Device with just one account Google (in android settings), it is ok

**More details :**
I debugged the application and the nativescript-oauth2 plugin.
I saw that the Google Frame with Waiting message (after choose a google account) send 2 events to Android with differents values for the "code" parameter.
Of course the first code is expired/revoked and Google return an error.

In the OAuth [Google documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/native-app#obtainingaccesstokens), this is the Step 4 which send 2 responses with 2 codes.

**My question**

Why the Google Frame browser send me 2 events ?

**Code :**

Here is my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="__PACKAGE__"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">

    <supports-screens
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true"/>

    <application
        android:name="com.tns.NativeScriptApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity
            android:name="com.tns.NativeScriptActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_kimera"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout|locale|uiMode"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchScreenTheme">

            <meta-data android:name="SET_THEME_ON_LAUNCH" android:resource="@style/AppTheme" />

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <!-- Custom URL Schemes -->
                <data android:path="/auth"
                      android:scheme="com.googleusercontent.apps.xxxxxxxx-yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.tns.ErrorReportActivity"/>

        <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
                android:value="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" />
    </application>

    <uses-sdk
            android:minSdkVersion="17"
            android:targetSdkVersion="__APILEVEL__"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"  />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: Don't know if this helps but do check it out .. https://github.com/gigya/cordova-plugin-gigya/issues/5 perhaps it affects your case also.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. No, it did not help me. I don't understand on my phone why I have to wait ?? It is weird, but I think there is a logical answer...

Comment: I think it has to do with the signing process that is used in authenticating with Google https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/62984/could-the-reference-of-the-perfect-year-from-plato-indicate-that-people-where to be more precise here it indicates something that might take some time depending the OS version https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/native-app#obtainingaccesstokens

Comment: I mean this part `A code_verifier is a high-entropy cryptographic random string using the unreserved characters [A-Z] / [a-z] / [0-9] / "-" / "." / "_" / "~", with a minimum length of 43 characters and a maximum length of 128 characters.`. As i remember high-entropy comes with a cost and depending perhaps OS version there could be variations on libraries of the system. https://medium.com/vault12/how-to-get-true-randomness-from-your-apple-device-with-particle-physics-and-thermal-entropy-a9d47ca80c9b

Comment: But i am not sure this is the reason. I hope it helps. Good question. Have you also tried reaching the author of the library? Perhaps it is a bug of the new version....

Comment: Thanks for your help. Yes an issue is open on github https://github.com/alexziskind1/nativescript-oauth2/issues/85  While debbuging the plugin, I saw 2 calls to Google. In the plugin, NativeScript listens the Android event as `Application.android.on(AndroidApplication.activityResumedEvent, (args))`, and 2 events are emitted with one error and one ok...